# Accurate numbering after cloned element is removed

Tags: jquery

here is the code that adds a new textarea with "remove" icon and one stop increased ID. (please check link to fiddle below )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  i = 1;
  $('.add').click(function() {

    i++

    $(".append_data").append('<div class="textarea_cloned" id="' + i + '"><textarea name=txt_' + i + '>Textarea ' + i + '</textarea><div data-id="' + i + '" class="remove"> X </div></div>');
  });

  $('.append_data').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    //$(this).closest('.textarea_cloned').remove();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#' + id + '').remove();
    return false;
  });

  // end of it all
});
```

When I click "add" once -  a new textarea is being generated with ID 2... then I decided to remove it. Then I click "add' again and what I'd like to get is ID 2 again but it will be ID 3. I know I have explained it a bit messy. Here is the desired algorithm:

1. click "add new textarea"
2. click "X" (to remove it)
3. click "add new textarea" again and it should have ID 2 instead of ID 3.

Here is Fiddle for your convenience:
https://jsfiddle.net/7avs08cx/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `i--;` after `$('#' + id + '').remove();`.

Comment: just realized it should be so, damn =)))
 i = id-1;
night..heh....Thanks man!
one more question if you dont mind (a harder one) -  what if I add, let's say, five new textareas and wil remove #3 and #4... how to arrange the rest from 1 to 3 ?

maybe I should post it as a separate question?

Comment: Well, you need to re arrange all the text areas on every click of remove

Comment: Thank you so much Rehban! I'll try to figure out how to set var i to the last (biggest) id myself. Thank you!!!!

Comment: i = j-1;
to reset the last id (after sorting is done)
Thanks once again,sir!

Comment: My pleasure to help you sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count of text areas you have done and then proceed.
I have created unique class for counting class name : `txtarea`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.add').click(function() {
     var i = $('.txtarea').length;
   i = i+1;
 $(".append_data").append('<div class="textarea_cloned txtarea" id="' + i + '"><textarea name=txt_' + i + '>Textarea ' + i + '</textarea><div data-id="' + i + '" class="remove"> X </div></div>');
  });

  $('.append_data').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#' + id + '').remove();
    return false;
  });

  // end of it all
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="old">
  <textarea>Textarea 1</textarea>
</form>
<div class="txtarea append_data"></div>
<div class="add">Add new text area</div>
```